# What coastal ports in Norway ship to Toronto, Canada? Disregard Oslo

Tags: canada, norway, shipping

My sister needs to ship [choses in possession](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/24179)  from [**Ikornnes**](https://www.google.com/maps/place/J.E.+Ekornes+AS/@62.3824296,5.7025562,9z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x4616c0aa5ac093ff:0xaf9fb1bdc28a2637!8m2!3d62.3870645!4d6.5554151) (Western Norway)  to Toronto (Canada) — like  her pricey sofa, mattress, office chair — all made in Norway!

Obviously it wastes fuel and time to truck her choses from Ikkornes to Oslo — because Ikornnes is right on the coast of the Norwegian Sea, and Oslo is inland. It's foolish to truck her choses inland, then have the ship sail back out to the Norwegian Sea. It's more productive to truck her choses to a coastal port (e.g. ***Ålesund, 31 km to the northwest of Ikornnes)***, then ship directly to Toronto.

**Which of the following ports ship directly to Toronto? Overlook Oslo**. I cannot deduce which, from this [Feb 2019 map](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Map-showing-the-container-ports-of-Norway_fig1_331153867)

[image]

and the [Norwegian Maritime Authority's 2012 Guide to Norwegian Ports](https://www.sdir.no/globalassets/sjofartsdirektoratet/fartoy-og-sjofolk---dokumenter/arbeids--og-levevilkar---dokumenter/guide-to-norwegian-ports-2012-web.pdf), page 3.

[image]

Ikornnes is in the county of [Møre og Romsdal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B8re_og_Romsdal).

Comment: None of those ports ship to Toronto.  Ports don't ship.  Shippers ship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ports don't ship anything to anywhere. Even if you find a ship that sails from one of these ports and happens to reach Canada, it is unlikely that it would reach Toronto. There are [ways to get to the Great Lakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Lawrence_Seaway) from the Atlantic Ocean, but not every vessel can go through them, and when they go through them they're more likely to reach [Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton-Oshawa_Port_Authority) than Toronto.

That said, even if you find a ship that sails from one of these ports and ends up in Toronto, **you** are unlikely to be able to put anything on that ship yourself. You'll need a shipping agent to do that for you, who will hire a shipping company, who can then add your cargo to one of its containers.

So instead of trying to figure out ships and ports, try to figure out shipping agents and companies. Find one that can pick up the cargo from your home in Norway, bring it to the location desired in Toronto, and relieve yourself of any worry about *how exactly* they're going to do that. There may even be planes involved, likely trains, and quite surely automobiles.